# Awesomium WebView not rendering video and flash files in html file

Tags: javascript, html, cocoa, flash, awesomium

I have html content which contains swf file.

```
<object width="400" height="400" data="/Volumes/Development/Test/sample/sample.swf" />
```

These swf file is rendering properly in web view using Awesomium 1.6.6.. Recently, I have upgrade to Awesomium 1.7.4.2, and load the same file to load using web view.

The code is below

```
WebURL url(WSLit("file:///Volumes/Development/Test/sample.html"));
view_->web_view()->LoadURL(url);
```

Now, the sample html file does not render the swf file. Is the re anything that I am missing 
I have set the property of Webpreference though these are set to true by default.
`enable_plugins = true`,
`enable_javascript = true` are automatically set.

Let me know if any thing is missing. While the rest of the html content are rendering, only the swf files are not rendering on the the web view.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problems. The solution was to wrap the swf file in an html file with valid tags, like you did. But I found that it is important to specify the correct type. The type should be "application/x-shockwave-flash". It can only help to use all the required html tags, although it should work without them too. In your case try this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="400" height="400" data="/Volumes/Development/Test/sample/sample.swf"></object>
</body>
</html>
```